# Move div having same id

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so i have dragged div with same id multiple time in other div, now i want to move this up and down onclick. 
Is there any way to accomplish this using javascript.

Comment: it is not valid markup to have multiple elements with the same ID on a page. It will fail w3c validation and cause problems with javascript that triies to manipulate by id - as you;re discovering

Comment: Each id should be unique in the page, that's why they are called 'ids'. If you have lots of things that you want to behave in a similar way it is generally accepted that you use a common class name instead. I know it doesn't answer your question, but it's very important. It may well be the cause of your difficulties writing JavaScript to manipulate the divs too.

Comment: Here's the w3c reference http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: `cloneItem.id = new Date().valueOf();` should give the new dv a different id....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never assign same id to different elements. it is not valid, id has to be unique.

if you must have all of them id-ed by '1' then rather assign all of them a class named '1' like this:

```
<div class="upDownDiv" id="stage" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="text-align: center;display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
            <div class='1'>
                <button style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>


            <div class='1'>
                <button style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>

           <div class='1'>
                <button style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
     </div>
```

to access all of the divs with class '1' later simply do a

```
var myDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('1');
```

and then iterate through them one by one and do your bidding.
or use jQuery and handle all of them same time.

Comment: But i am using it for drag and drop purpose, if i assign a class to all of them then how will drag and drop it using class name?

Comment: using jQuery, you can use the $(".1") selector (assuming the css class is named "1" as in the answer above)

Comment: Should i post my javascript code for drag and drop??

Comment: Downvoters please don't downvote as i am new to programming. please

Comment: @RS26 your argument is invalid. "But i am using it for drag and drop purpose".  it makes absolutely zero difference what your intentions are, id should be unique, always, period, end of discussion. either assign unique id per div, or set them a common class.